# JAVA,JSON и ассоциативные массивы

Tags: java, массивы, json

Мне нужно превратить объект json в ассоциативный массив. Пытался на GSONе , но как я понял, нужно знать ключи от значений в json'е.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так:

```
import javax.json.JsonArray;
import javax.json.JsonException;
import javax.json.JsonObject;

public static Map<String, Object> jsonToMap(JSONObject json) throws JSONException {
        Map<String, Object> retMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    if(json != JSONObject.NULL) {
        retMap = toMap(json);
    }
    return retMap;
}

public static Map<String, Object> toMap(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    Iterator<String> keysItr = object.keys();
    while(keysItr.hasNext()) {
        String key = keysItr.next();
        Object value = object.get(key);

        if(value instanceof JSONArray) {
            value = toList((JSONArray) value);
        }

        else if(value instanceof JSONObject) {
            value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
        }
        map.put(key, value);
    }
    return map;
}

public static List<Object> toList(JSONArray array) throws JSONException {
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        Object value = array.get(i);
        if(value instanceof JSONArray) {
            value = toList((JSONArray) value);
        }

        else if(value instanceof JSONObject) {
            value = toMap((JSONObject) value);
        }
        list.add(value);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Код взят отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21720759/convert-a-json-string-to-a-hashmap

Comment: Спасибо)а как можно обратиться к элементу массива(и если можно пример для многомерного массива

Comment: К элементу ассоциативного массива (он же `Map`) можно обратиться либо при переборе элементов массива:

`for (Map.Entry<Object, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {

  entry.getKey(); //получаем ключ

  entry.getValue(); //получаем значение`

либо по ключу:

`Object value = map.get("FieldName");`