# Парсинг ассоциативных массивов json java

Tags: java, json

Мне нужно спарсить данные в следующие классы. Я раньше не сталкивался с JSON.

```
  public class State {
    public String name;
    public LinkedList<Point> points;
}



  public class Point {
public double latitude;
public double longitude;
}
```

Данные: [States.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ue6BAem3rb8Pra5gQXkoKsCFkc909nUz/view)

Сложность заключается в том, что название ключей я не знаю и у каждого штата
может быть вложенность как 4 так и 2 , т.е ассоциативные массивы. Я смотрел дубликаты, в частности этот [java,json и ассоц.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503736/java-json-%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B) но у меня не получилось.

На выходе я бы хотел получить лист из State , где в каждом State хранится лист из Point.

Comment: Любая библиотека ,json подойдет

Comment: Можете воспользоватся библиотекой Gson, как по мне там очень удобный механизм кастомизации процесса парсинга. [тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/950546/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-gson-%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2-json/951598#951598)